# How to define the "domain" of a function as D = ...?

Tags: functions, notation

I am working on modeling math stuff with a custom [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), and am working on how to model things that have structures, such as the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)), or the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of a function. I am able to model theorems if they only involve logical equations (boolean statement trees), and proofs as a bunch of *transformations*, but now wondering how to model the construction of objects and definition of them.

This question is about the domain of a function.

> the **domain** or set of departure of a function is the set into which all of the input of the function is constrained to fall.

So it's basically a set of all possible inputs.

I am not able to capture this in a DSL currently. All the information I am able to capture is this basically:

```
object(domain) :=
  prop(set, type: Set)
```

It has no notion that the set is part of the possible inputs to the function. How would you write this definition in formal logic notation, to capture more of the inner details of what a domain really is?

I want to say something more like:

```
domain = set where set is possible input to function
```

But maybe it's a circular argument, because "possible input to function" *is the domain*.

$$f : D \to C$$

Do we just say that the $D \in f$ is the domain? Is there anything more that can be done?

$$D = \{x | x \in f \}$$

Something like that, but I can't seem to figure out how to drill into it properly.

Sorry if this seems like a weird question, I am just coming at mathematics from a different angle and trying to model it accurately in code. Basically I would like a standalone definition of a domain, not a definition that is nested inside the definition of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're implementing functions in the first place.

The set-theoretic approach, which is more streamlined but less common outside of logic, is that a function is simply a set of ordered pairs such that nothing occurs as the left coordinate of two distinct pairs. According to this approach the domain is simply $$\{x:\exists y((x,y)\in f)\}.$$ Note that in this approach we do *not* have a "codomain" as such.

The more common approach is that a function is a *triple* $(D,C,G)$ of sets such that $G\subseteq D\times C$ and every element of $D$ is the left coordinate of exactly one element of $G$. Here the domain is the first coordinate of the function itself; note that this approach is really a special case of *arbitrary relations* with specified domain and codomain (for that we only require $G\subseteq D\times C$).

Which approach is appropriate for you will of course depend on your specific goals and aesthetic preferences.